# best c++11 way to store a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, vector, stl

I want to store a vector of `std::threads`

Currently, I implemented it as `std::vector<std::thread*>`
However, this requires manually deleting the `std::thread`s

What would be the most elegant c++11 way to do this? I could see `std::shared_ptr`, but isn't it an overkill? The pointers are unique, but `std::vector` needs to copy them temporarily.

Maybe I do not need pointers, but `std::thread` being non copyable, I think I do.

Thanks!

Comment: No, `std::vector` supports move-only types. If you ever do need a vector of pointers, you could look into `boost::ptr_vector`.

Comment: "However, this requires manually deleting the std::threads" Why does everyone assume every pointer has to be deleted?

Comment: @juanchopanza because every object allocated with new needs to be deleted  -- either explicitly or via RAII (smartpointer).

Comment: @DaleWilson And every pointer has to point to an object allocated with new now?

Comment: If you aren't planning on copying the `std::thread*` could you just use `std::unique_ptr`, you just need to ensure you use the moving ways of getting values of of the `std::vector`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since C++11, `vector` only requires that its values are movable, as `thread` is. So `vector<thread>` should meet your needs.

There are a few restrictions on what you can do with non-copyable types - you can't copy values in or out, only move or emplace them - but these are easy to accommodate.

If you did need to store unmovable types (`mutex`, for example), then `unique_ptr` is probably the best option; or a container like `deque` or `list` that doesn't need to move its values.

Answer (score 4):

Yoy may use `std::vector<std::thread>` and `emplace_back`:

```
threads.emplace_back([](int i){ ++i; }, 10);
```

`emplace_back` uses perfect forwarding to pass its arguments directly to `std::thread` constructor, and places new object in `vector` internal memory, something like:

```
new (vector_ptr + offset) std::thread(args...);
```

It only involves *moving* - a new semantics of handling objects which is alternative to *copying* and may be cheaper in terms of resource usage. `std::thread` supports *moving*.

Comment: @rici: Threads are movable, which is enough to resize a vector.

Comment: @rici, if you know maximum number of threads, you may simply call `reserve()`

Comment: @myaut: That wouldn't help if the type really were unmovable; the compiler would still need to generate the code to resize, even if it never gets called. But the question is about a movable type, so using a vector is fine whether or not it needs resizing.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Of course, I assume that question is about `vector<thread>` (as first sentence of OP post says). However, I checked gcc -- it seems that `emplace_back()` requires moving and will not work for non-moveable types.

Comment: @myaut: emplace_back requires moving (to compile) because it may call resize, and the vector doesn't know that you've already reserved as much space as you might need. As per Mike's previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

use std::unique_ptr if your compiler supports c++11, or boost::shared_ptr if your compiler does not.

No, it is not overkill -- it is good programming.

Comment: Why not `std::thread` itself? It's just as movable as `unique_ptr`. Adding unnecessary indirection is overkill, and isn't good programming. (And if the compiler doesn't support C++11, it doesn't support threads)

Comment: Good point.  I was focusing on the issue of pointers, not threads (see the title to the question)  If the objects are movable (which threads are)  your answer is better.

Comment: Why & how would one use `std::shared_ptr` on a non-C++11 compiler?

Comment: @JohnDibling `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<whatever> >` works just fine.  std::shared_ptrs are movable and copyable, even if the `whatever` is not.

Comment: @DaleWilson:  Let me be less ambigious:  `std::shared_ptr` was added to C++11.  If one doesn't have a C++11 compiler, one can't use `std::shared_ptr`'

Comment: Ah:  one can call it boost::shared_ptr.  I tend to put the two in the same mental pigeon-hole.  Thanks for pointing that out.