# Parallel dictionary cracker with c++ threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, invoke

I am learning to better use threads in C++ and this is my end of semester assignment. I am trying to create a fairly simple dictionary cracker program that takes a .txt  file and copies each word in a vector; the vector is split in "sectors" of equal length (number of words per sector) in order to be parallelized. Then the program starts threads that take as parameters 2 iterators, pointing to the beginning and end of a sector. Each thread, when constructed, will deal with the sector immediately following the previous one.

A thread function will thus go through each word of the vector sector between the beginning and end iterators, compute the hash of it and check it against the hash of the password I need to crack. I am using a mutex when actually accessing the particular word the iterator points to, although I am not entirely sure if this is the correct approach to it.

For now, my problem is that I am getting 2 compile errors:

> Error C2672   'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found    DictionaryCrackerEC d:\programs\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread 240
>
> Error C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'    DictionaryCrackerEC d:\programs\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread 240

and I've no idea which line exactly do they come from, and how to solve it. I've looked into various "invoke" issues online, but I either don't understand them, or they seem related to classes member functions calls and things like that, while I don't even have classes in my program yet.

That's the theory, here's the actual code for my main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <openssl\md5.h>
using namespace std;

//determine the best number of threads based on hardware
const int PC_THREADS_NUM = thread::hardware_concurrency();
mutex password_mutex;

int main()
{
    vector<string> passwdVector;
    vector<string>::const_iterator beginIter, endIter;
    passwdVector.reserve(18000);
    //code here that loads words from .txt file into passwdVector

    string userPassword = "";
    cout << "please insert the password that you'd like to crack: ";
    cin >> userPassword;

    //splitting the vector into sections to parallelize
    int sectionLength = passwdVector.size() / PC_THREADS_NUM;
    beginIter = passwdVector.begin();
    endIter = beginIter + sectionLength;
    vector<thread*> sliceHashingThreads;
    for (int i = 0; i < PC_THREADS_NUM; i++)
    {
        sliceHashingThreads.push_back(new thread(sliceHashCompare, std::ref(passwdVector), userPassword, beginIter, endIter, i));
        beginIter = endIter + 1;
        endIter += sectionLength;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sliceHashingThreads.size(); i++)
    {
        sliceHashingThreads[i]->join();
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the sliceHashCoompare function:

```
    void sliceHashCompare(vector<string>& passwordList, string& password, vector<string>::const_iterator beginIter, vector<string>::const_iterator endIter, int& threadID)
{
    string vectorElement = "", hashedElement = "";
    bool isPassFound = false;
    while (isPassFound != true)
    {
        for (; beginIter <= endIter; ++beginIter)
        {
            password_mutex.lock();
            vectorElement = *beginIter;
            password_mutex.unlock();
            cout << threadID << " is processing word: " << vectorElement << endl;
            //Sleep(100);
            hashedElement = md5Hash(vectorElement);
            if(hashedElement == md5Hash(password))
            {
                isPassFound = true;
                cout << "The password was found! " << password << endl;
                cout << "Hash value: " << hashedElement << endl;
            }
        }
        if(isPassFound == false)
        {
            cout << "Password not found in the dictionary" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

When a password is found, I think I'd need a conditional variable that would stop all the other threads. Another thing I am considering is implementing a farmer/worker system later on, that would split the vector in a lot more smaller sectors and have a queue of tasks to keep giving threads work to do when one has finished. But for now I'm sticking with 8 threads (thread::hardware_concurrency) and have something working well, and I'll make improvements only afterwards. But any tips, suggestions and perhaps explanations are greatly appreciated, as I am looking to learn.

Really hoping that someone could explain me what is going wrong and make me understand how to fix it and why. Thank you so much in advance for any of your help!

Comment: You might want to simplify your code ([mcve]) to make your question easier (i.e. increase your chances of getting a useful answer)

Comment: Try removing every line of code that is not relevant. That is: for each line of code, if removing it from the code still demonstrates the problem (compilation error), **remove it**! You don't need to show code that does useful work - you only need to show code that demonstrates the error you are trying to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two main problems - you can't copy a std::thread, but you can move it, so move it into your vector

```
sliceHashingThreads.push_back(
           std::move(new thread(sliceHashCompare,
                                std::ref(passwdVector),
                                userPassword,
                                beginIter,
                                endIter,
                                i)));
```

Also, observe that if you just try to call your function,

```
sliceHashCompare(std::ref(passwdVector), userPassword, beginIter, endIter, 0);
```

you will also get an error - because it takes the threadID as a ref, if you change it to `int threadID` it will be fine.

VS gives a "user friendly" error list, but if you look at the full output (find under View | Output) if it's not already open then trawl through the errors until it mentions your code.

It should now compile and link. You have other probelms though. Who will delete your threads? See e.g. [best c++11 way to store a vector of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037929/best-c11-way-to-store-a-vector-of-pointers)

---

Of course, you don't need to move the pointer to a thread; the problem was the `int &` (and not deleting the pointers).

You could use a `std::vector<std::thread>` though by using `std::move` or

```
sliceHashingThreads.emplace_back(sliceHashCompare, 
       std::ref(passwdVector),
       userPassword, beginIter, endIter, i);
```

You could also use `std::ref(i)` for your last parameter to avoid changing the `sliceHashCompare` function.

Comment: exactly, I have the vectors as pointers, but the threadID issue was indeed the problem. And to think I added that only for debugging purpose, to see what each thread is doing. Thank you @doctorlove
Just out of curiosity, was it because threadID was not inside the mutex area?

Comment: BTW - you haven't locked the mutex, or I'm missing something

Comment: Yes I did, I mean I lock the mutex, dereference beginIter, and then I unlock it immediately after. If that's not what you were talking about, then please make me understand better

Comment: Ah - yes - seen it now